# showing error in parent object if two objects have M-D relationship

Tags: custom-object, opportunity, error-messages

My objects: Opportunity and custom object(CE) have M-D relation ship

Is it possible to check the child object fields on stage change in opportunity and throw the error if child object fields are blank.

Comment: Please let me know how we can achieve this.. any alternatives/suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a checkbox field on Child called `is_incomplete_for_stageX__c`
2. Populate it with a Process Flow/Workflow field update by examining the other child fields for presence/absence. Populate on every create/edit child event
3. Create RSF on Opportunity that counts the children where `is_incomplete_for_stageX__c` is true
4. Create Validation rule on Opportunity where `if stage changes to Foo and RSF > 0, then error`

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'd need to have a trigger that fired which queried all the child records for the opportunity. I don't know if you have a many to one relationship with your child records or not, but it's certainly possible, thus the need to run a query. It could be done in either a before Update (best choice) or an After Update trigger. You'd then use the `add error` method in the trigger for any Opportunities that didn't return a child record for the CE object or one which had all empty fields, etc (would be up to you to set the criteria).